# Evaluating expressions in "case" vs using "if/else if"

Tags: javascript

I was just tempted to write a similar piece of code to the one presented in [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3463944/2913106) (posted below). The problem is having to discriminate between different cases where exactly *one* case is true.

In my experience `switch` statements are usually use to match the value of an expression against various constants. But in this case we use a `switch` statement to decide which of the conditions is `true`. To do this I would actually prefer using `if/else if` because `switch(true)` feels a little bit like an abuse of `switch`, but this is just a gut feeling. On the other hand I think this piece of code is still prefectly readable even with its seemingly unconventional use of a `switch` statement.

Are there any objective reasons why one would prefer `switch` over `if/else if` or vice versa when it comes to code quality, performance and readability?

```
switch (true) {
  case (amount >= 7500 && amount < 10000):
    //code
    break;
  case (amount >= 10000 && amount < 15000):
    //code
    break;

  //etc...
```

Comment: This question might be more on-topic over at https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/ . However, **before posting please [follow their tour](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask), ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).**

Comment: Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Please [follow the tour](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask), ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a review question. But as this will be closed I might as well give a quick answer. You should have asked this at SO.

`switch` statement are meant as a shortcut to long lists of simple `if (a == 1) else if (a == 2) else if (...`. They ended up in JS as that is what was needed to attract C/C++ coders to the language back in the day when JS was SLOW.

There is nothing wrong with using them but in most cases you can simplify with `if else`.

EG

```
// 3 logic operations
if (a >= 75) {   // 1
   if (a < 100) { ... } // 2 
   else if (a < 150) {/* 3 logic operations to get here */}  // 3
}

// 8 logic operations
switch (true) {  // this must evaluate on each case === true if you get to them
  case (a >= 75 && a < 100): //  1:(a >= 75)  2:(a < 100) 3:(&&) 4:(case === true)
    ...
    break;
  case (a >= 100 && a < 150): //  5:(a >= 100)  6:(a < 150) 7:(&&) 8:(case === true)
    /* 8 logic operations to get here */
    break;
```